# Recovery mode networking from clean install - resolve.conf: no such file or directory

Tags: boot, networking, recovery-mode

I'm unable to start networking in recovery mode - even from a clean install I get `resolve.conf: no such file or directory` warnings when I try to start it. Consequently I'm totally unable to run dpkg from recovery mode and if anything goes even slightly wrong my system is hosed and requires a full install.

Happens in both 16.04 and 16.10, clean installs of both.

It is making troubleshooting certain display problems frustrating in the extreme as I have to reinstall from scratch if there's even the smallest issue with a package - recovery mode is almost pointless.

*Edit*: resolv.conf exists. It contains the expected default Network Manager imposed nameserver line and nothing more. My network connection is a standard ethernet connection to a router (not that that should matter as it seemingly can't even find the file).

Comment: In Ubuntu, `/etc/resolv.conf` is generated by the `resolvconf` program. See `man resolvconf`.

Comment: Sure. It should be generated automatically on login. It is. It's there.

Recovery mode doesn't think so though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that while the network option loops the resolv.conf error and dumps me back to the recovery menu it does at least mount the filesystem and start the networking daemon.

As a result, selecting the root terminal afterwards means I can use it properly.